# Codeigniter interval in table rows

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

How can I retrieve interval of rows from selected table using CodeIgniter active record? Should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where min-row > 10 ORDER BY date asc LIMIT 10;
```

**EDIT**

Where min-row is not a table column, but row number.

To clear things up, lets say I want to select rows from 10 to 20 from the selected table.

**EDIT**

Ok, I learned that I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 10, 20;
```

How can I do this in active record?

Comment: SELECT * FROM is not active record structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$rs = $this->order_by("date", 'asc')->get('posts', 10, 10)->result_array();
```

Or,

```
$rs = $this->db->order_by("date", 'asc')->limit(10, 10)->get('posts')->result_array();
```

For example : `limit(10, 10)` will fetch 10 rows starting from 10th row. i.e the first parameter is the limit and second is the offset.

Comment: min row is not an existing column, but the index of column in the selected table.